How can I retrieve company name and position of a user using Linkedin developer API
After the OpenId update I can't see any way to retrieve company name and the user position

openid
Use your name and photo
profile
Use your name and photo
w_member_social
Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on your behalf
email
Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account

These are the only scopes I can see
        const positionResponse = await axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/positions', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${req.session.accessToken}` }
        });

and I tried to log the data I got
Error: {
  status: 404,
  code: 'RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND',
  message: 'No virtual resource found'
}


According to the docs, OpenID's profile scope is:

"Required to retrieve the member's lite profile including their id, name, and profile picture."

It doesn't provide information about the user's positions.
To access that, you should use /me with r_liteprofile or r_basicprofile, but note that access requires approval through the LinkedIn Partner Program.
See the LinkedIn API docs.
